# keras error: "AttributeError: can't set attribute" while defining a layer

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying t create my own layer in keras that I get error. my simple code is as below:

```
class MyLayer(Layer):

def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
    self.output_dim = output_dim

    self.updates = []

    super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='kernel', 
                                  shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                  initializer='uniform',
                                  trainable=True)
    super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!

def call(self, x):
    return K.dot(x, self.kernel)

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)
```

and the error is:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 MyLayer(output_dim=10)

in **init**(self, output_dim, **kwargs)

8         self.output_dim = output_dim

9

---> 10         self.updates = []

11

12         super(MyLayer, self).**init**(**kwargs)

AttributeError: can't set attribute

could you please help with this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to the issue in [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7736).

In that case, the OP was using the variable name *weights* instead of *kernal* which seems to be already used. If you look at the definition of **Layer** in [Tensroflow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer#updates), you'll see that *update* and *weights* are properties of the class **Layer**.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Tensorflow 2.0.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer

class MyLayer(Layer):
  def __init__(self, output_dim, **kwargs):
    self.output_dim = output_dim

    self.update = []

    super(MyLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

  def build(self, input_shape):
      # Create a trainable weight variable for this layer.
      self.my_kernel = self.add_weight(name='my_kernel', 
                                    shape=(input_shape[1], self.output_dim),
                                    initializer='uniform',
                                    trainable=True)
      super(MyLayer, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!

  def call(self, x):
      return K.dot(x, self.kernel)

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
      return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)

my_layer = MyLayer((1))
```